# How to get cookie using python request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
s.get('https://test.com',auth=('user','test'))
x=s.cookies
print(x)
```

This is my code and output is

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie __cfduid=asdasd1232fgdb323123 for .testcom/>, <Cookie JSESSIONID=123fdf54fgfa for test.com/gpcs-web-war>]>
```

now , i want to get cfduid and JSESSIONID how to extract from output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.get_dict()` on `s.cookies` and then the `[]` notation to scoop out the values.

For example:

```
s.cookies.get_dict()["JSESSIONID"]
```